# pros/cons of loading python modules from network location

Tags: python

I was wondering what are the downsides to loading python modules from a network location?

I've developed a few dozen python tools and I now want to share them across the team and each computer has Python27 locally installed. However they do not have all the necessary modules which my tool's use. All together there may be a total of two additional modules which my tool needs to import. I've decided to place these modules on the network. Then in my tool I just have:

```
sys.path.append('Z:\\pipeline\\site-packages')
import Shotgun
```

Is this a horrible idea? I find it super easy to manage and would rather do this then trying to manage installing all kinds of packages on users computers and whatnot.

I'm assuming it wouldn't be that taxing to load modules from dozens of artists across the network, since one the tool is loaded the module no longer needs to communicate with the network, right?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is.

Tying the code to a specific location is quite a bad idea, and here are just a few reasons.

- If you do not have a network connection, you won't be able to import
- If the network mapping somehow changes, you must update your code
- If you have to update or fix the module on the network, all its importers are immediately being affected

Those might look like little issues to you at the moment, but:
You will not be able to import that when your laptop is isolated from the network. You will have to update code revision(!) only to support a different location. You will have broken applications if an update in the network module requires a local update of its importer.

Never, ever, tie your code to its current random environment.

Answer (score 1):

How many machines/users you have in your team? What is the structure of that network location? What is the size of the files(modules) you have there? Is it possible that all users will try to load the modules in the same time?

Basically if your team is small, you shouldn't really be worried about it. Not the best solution (mostly because you can easily install these modules using `pip install` or `easy_install`, but if your team is getting bigger (or if you use a cluster and try to run the same code on 1000's machines concurrently) - you might have problems there.

If your storage is not designed for multiple machines-access (caching/distributing/raid) - you might get into trouble if you will get big.

You can read more about [distributed file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_systems#Distributed_parallel_fault-tolerant_file_systems) which give a solution for such cases.